# how to read shapeFile Attribute (access Attribute Table) in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, shapefile

I am using Node.js and https://www.npmjs.com/package/shapefile package to read **Shape file**  but my code only read the **coordinates** of Geo shapes **shape file**  . i want to have access to **attribute** of my **Shape file**  how can i solve this problem ??

```
const shapefile = require("shapefile");

let MyData =[];
shapefile.open(addr)
        .then(source => source.read()
          .then(function log(result) {
            if (result.done) return;
            console.log(result);
            MyData.push(result.value);
            return source.read().then(log);
          }))
        .catch(error => console.error(error.stack))
        .then(()=>{
          res.send(MyData);
        });
```

Comment: `MyData` isn't declared in your example

Comment: you have to do `const MyData = []` to be able to push to it.

Comment: yeah,thanks but I do not write all of my code here !

Comment: in my own version I declared that and my Code runs without bug and it read shape file but not contain all of info that exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean attributes that you can see in ARCGIS software, you should read `.dbf` files for that purpose you can use `dbf-reader` package